# Execute Asynchronusly in for loop in javascript to retrive sharepoint list items

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I want to retrieve list items based on passing values to query from array. Due to asynchronous functionality its not reading all the items.

Below is the code

```
for(i=0; i<= DepartmentIds.length; i++)
  {
       ReadDepartmentDetails([DepartmentIds[i]]);

  }

 var depemail;
 var depId;
 var ndesId;
 var d;

function ReadDepartmentDetails(ndesId)
{
 //    alert(DepartmentIds);
     d = $.Deferred();
   currentSiteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    currentContext = getClientContext();

    this.website = currentContext.get_web();
    this.currentUser = website.get_currentUser();
    var oList = currentContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Department');
     var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();  
       // '<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="ID" /><Value Type="Number">"ndesId"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>';


        camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Number'>" + ndesId + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
      this.ocamlItems = oList.getItems(camlQuery); 


    currentContext.load(ocamlItems);

    currentContext.executeQueryAsync(  
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.RetriveEmailSucceed),  
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)  
        );  
return d.promise(); 
}

function RetriveEmailSucceed(sender, args)
{
    depemail = ocamlItems.get_item('Email');
     alert(depemail);
}
```

Comment: A quick note: You can either use async/await which changes asynchronous calls into synchronous or you will need to make your function recursive to handle the repeated calls.
Async/await is easiest but may not work on all browsers

Comment: If your query fetches more than 100 values you need to set ROWLIMIT value set to more than 100 in your CAML query.